# Hosts file name lookups not working

Tags: windows-server-2003, hosts

My x64 windows 2003 box is not resolving names in the hosts file in system32\drivers\etc.  I have been testing with nslookup with no luck.

There was not a syswow64\drivers\etc\hosts so I created one and entered the same hosts also with no luck.  Should I reboot to get this one to work?

I've done the ipconfig /flushdns and /registerdns a few times with no luck.

Comment: `nslookup` communicates directly with your DNS server, so it would not look at your hosts file.  You'd want to use `ping` or some other application that uses the normal methods to resolve a hostname and lets you know what IP it got.

Comment: aaah you are correct.  I thought by changing the server used to 127.0.0.1 it would work, but with some testing that doesn't appear to be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forgive me if the response is to basic.  It is quite unusual that this is not working and it appears you have taken all of the right steps.  Something as simple as the hosts file should just work when entries are being added to this file.

Take a look at Microsoft KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034
are there any other uncommented out lines in the hosts file aside from the ip and host to resolve?

Comment: Thanks I re-created the hosts file and it works now. Can't believe something so simple escaped me for that long.